# Uncheck Succeeding Radio Buttons upon clicking a radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm building a conditional logic survey.

I want to uncheck all the radio buttons present after the radio button I just click - even those belonging to other radio groups. In short - empty the form the point at which I click but keep the rest of the earlier part of the form intact.

Is there any way to do this with jQuery? Something automatic and fast?

Comment: This is what radio buttons are for -- checking one will uncheck the others automatically. You do, however, need to give all the radio buttons in a group the same "name" attribute.

Comment: Just added some details to the questions to make it clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

for check selected or remove selected attrib of inputs , use :

```
$('.myinputsOrinput').attr("selected", true)
$('.myinputsOrinput').attr("selected", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient (or at least most clear) way is to clear all radio buttons, then re-check the one you've clicked:

```
$("#radio_clear").click(function(){
    $("input:radio").prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
})
```

Comment: but this doesn't take care of the form filled upto the point where I click.

Comment: I've misunderstood your question, then. Please provide a more complete sample of your html code.